# How to create a dropdown for ios using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I can create a dropdown for android using DropdownButton and DropdownMenuItem widgets.But for ios I couldn't see any widgets like dropdown. I have seen on Cupertino (iOS-style) widgets also, but I didn't get any idea.Is there any option to create a dropdown for ios?

Answer (score 8):

In iOS, the dropdown known as Picker. You can try the Cupertino Picker Widget.

Here is the Documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html

And Here is the repo with an example, that will show you how you can implement: https://github.com/dhuma1981/Flutter_Cupertino_Demo