# IOS style menu item popover for dropdown in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, drop-down-menu, styles, menuitem

How can I get drop menu item pop over like below image in flutter

[UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8AM9.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a dropdown for ios using flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663309/how-to-create-a-dropdown-for-ios-using-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

Flutter has a native implementation for that: [CupertinoContextMenu](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoContextMenu-class.html)

Comment: How to open it by click?